# Our plugin tags not appearing in WordPress Plugin Repository

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, readme

We have an appointment calendar plugin at WordPress Plugin Repository.

In our plugin **`readme.txt`**, we have already added tags like:

```
=== Appointment Calendar ===
Contributors: a.ankit, FARAZFRANK, harimaliya 
Link: http://appointzilla.com/
Tags: appointment, booking, calendar, appointment scheduling calendar, appointment calendar
Requires at least: 3.3+
Tested up to: 3.4.2
Stable tag: 2.4
```

**Readme Snap:** 
[image]

you can check our plugin **`readme.txt`** file at WordPress Plugin Repository: **[here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/appointment-calendar/)**

But these tags  are not appearing after plugin description at WordPress Plugin Repository.

If anybody have any knowledge about this issue then help me. Thanks...

Comment: This question should be asked at WordPRess.com. See the [faq].

Comment: We already did it, no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [attack yesterday](http://lists.automattic.com/pipermail/wp-hackers/2013-January/045123.html) on WP servers, make a small push and try again.

First, run the [readme validator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/validator/) and make sure yours matches as much as possible the [official example](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/readme.txt).

Comment: Thanks mate, there was mistake with donate link, we corrected. It's working now.